# auto deployment of code in jenkins based on git in assembla

Tags: git, jenkins, assembla

I am able to configure jenkins with the git repository. I want to perform an auto deployment when ever there is any push done into the git repository. I am using git repository provided by assembla.

I followed the given link "https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Assembla+Merge+Request+Builder+Plugin". But I was not able to deploy the code on push command.

I am able achive auto deployment by creating a post-commit file into the hooks folder of .git and adding the following command curl "http://JENKINS_URL/jenkins/job/xxxx/build?delay=0sec". with this I am able to perform auto deployment on the commit. I want to know if there is any better approach.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the method KK suggests here : [Polling must die: triggering Jenkins builds from a git hook](http://kohsuke.org/2011/12/01/polling-must-die-triggering-jenkins-builds-from-a-git-hook/)

From the Git Plugin [Documentation](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin) :

> To minimize the delay between a push and a build, it is recommended to
>   set up the post-receive hook in the repository to poke Jenkins when a
>   new push occurs. To do this, add the following line in your
>   hooks/post-receive file, where  is the
>   fully qualified URL you use when cloning this repository.

```
curl http://yourserver/git/notifyCommit?url=<URL of the Git repository>[&branches=branch1[,branch2]*][&sha1=<commit ID>]
```

Comment: Thanks cole. I tried the given approach and I was able to do the deployement on the push.

Comment: @Cole9350 I already set a webhook with external URL set to "http://111.111.111.111/git/notifyCommit?url=%{repository_url}&branch=%{branch}" and set the jenkins job to assembla on push and nothing happen.... can you explain some more?

Comment: @DoronShai Please create a new question with the issues you are having and I will see if I can help. initially I would suggest using http:// as a part of your git url

Answer (score 0):

[assembla.com](http://www.assembla.com?affiliate=acroitor) has a webhook tool, you can find under Admin>Tools and you can configure that to fire your jenkins build on every commit.

Or you can configure jenkins to poll every X mins, hours to run the build

Comment: Thanks for the information. But it was not ececuting the build on the push command. And as you have mentined to poll for X min. That is working fine, but my actual I have to execute the build on the push command.

Comment: Worth to note that this is a paid feature. You must upgrade your account to be able to use it.